# v-bind:key в v-for error

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

У меня есть переменная file_url в которая может содержать любое количество адресов для загрузки файлов или не содержать вовсе. Я пытаюсь вывести  все адреса при помощи v-for,но получаю ошибку.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="load_file">
            <input type="file" @change="onFileChanged">
            <button @click="onUpload">Загрузить</button>
        </div>
        <div id="show_files">
            <div v-if="file_url">
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="url in file_url">
                        <a href={{url}} >Скачать файл</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>





<script>
    import Vue from "vue"
    import axios from 'axios'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'
    export default
    {
        data()
        {
            return
            {
                selectedFile: null
                file_url: false
            }
        },

        methods:
        {
            onFileChanged (event) {
                this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]
                console.log("choose",this.selectedFile)
            },


            onUpload()
            {
                const formData = new FormData()
                formData.append("image",this.selectedFile, 
                  this.selectedFile.name)
                formData.append("userImages",1)
                axios.post("http://127",formData)
                .then(response => {
                    if(response)
                    {
                    console.log("файл отправлен,ответ -  ",response)
                    }       })
            },
        },

        created() {
                if (process.client) {
                    if(this.$cookies.get('token'))
                    {
                        if(!this.$store.getters.USER_DATA)
                        {

                          this.$store.dispatch("LOGIN_ACTION_UPDATE")
                        }
                        this.file_url = 
                         this.$store.getters.USER_DATA.file_url
                    }
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

[image: Ошибка]
Буду благодарен за любую помощь,подсказки и замечания.

Comment: Михаил, ну очевидно же что на скрине вам даже описание ошибок выводится. Отсутствует атрибут `key` при рендеринге списков, для чего он нужен чётко написано в мануале. Интерполяция `{{}}` внутри атрибутов запрещена, это уже ошибка движка, про это также написано в мануале.

Comment: `href={{url}}` -> `:href="url"`

Comment: Ответ ниже правильный,  и grundy тоже дал верное дополнение для бинда нужно использовать его вариант

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно добавить атрибут `key`:

```
v-for="(url, index) in file_url" :key="index"
```

А атрибут `href` необходимо завебайндить и передавать в него переменную без интерполяции

Comment: Кто минуснул ответ он правильный `<li v-for="(url, index) in file_url" :key="index">`